# POST Uint16Array, work on the array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, binary

I wish to convert an array in JS to Uint16Array, POST using AJAX, receive in PHP, convert the POST to a PHP array.

So far:

JS

```
var data = [];

for(var j = 0; j < 4800; j++) {
  data.push(j);  
}

bytesToSendCount = data.length;

var bytesArray = new Uint16Array(bytesToSendCount);
for (var i = 0, l = bytesToSendCount; i < l; i++) {
  bytesArray[i] = data[i];
}

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php",
    data: bytesArray,
    contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
    processData: false,
    success: function(data){        
    console.log("ok");
    },
    failure: function(errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
  });
```

PHP

```
$data=file_get_contents('php://input');
```

How can i make $data to a PHP array? Maybe convert it to a ascii string, than convert it to a array?

EDIT:
The idea is to have a data logger working at 40SPS and send data to server using mobile internet. The problem in sending JSON or string or something isnit binary, its consuming a lot of data (24kb every two minutes), so using Uint16Array (the logger works at 16bits) reduce the POST to ~9kb/2minutes.

Comment: should not `$data = eval($data);` do the trick? If not, what exactly do you have in `$data`?

Comment: `$data` is just the post from AJAX (Uint16Array), using eval i get this message  `syntax error, unexpected 'D8APxA' (T_STRING)`.

Comment: huh? Can you please make a var_dump($data) and post the output of this here? I don't really see why it would be D8APxA or something like that.

Comment: The output without `eval` is a bit huge, something like this: ��������

Comment: I reduced the JS array to 40 elements. The output: http://textuploader.com/5pane

Comment: What's the point of all this? Why not just post it in the normal way and access it with `$_POST['parameter']`?

Comment: Anyway, I think you need to use `unpack()` in PHP to parse it.

Comment: I added the reason of using Uint16Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unpack` in PHP.

```
$array = unpack('n*', $data); // big-endian
```

or

```
$array = unpack('v*', $data); // little-endian
```

It's machine-dependent whether the data is sent in big-endian or little-endian order. You may want to use [Dataview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) so you can control this, then use the appropriate format in PHP.

Comment: That worked! Thanks for pointing out big/little endian. Now i can access the array ex: `$array[12]`. Many thanks!